# python-docx cannot be imported to python

Tags: python, docx, python-2.6, easy-install, python-docx

I'm trying to install python-docx so I typed in the cmd

```
easy_install python-docx
```

and got:

```
Searching for python-docx
Best match: python-docx 0.7.4
Processing python_docx-0.7.4-py2.6.egg
python-docx 0.7.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.7.4-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for python-docx
Finished processing dependencies for python-docx
```

but when I open python and type:

> import docx

I got:

```
 File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\docx-0.2.4-py2.6.egg\docx.py", line 17, in <
module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

How can I solve this import error? what is missing?

Comment: May be you need this "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.2.3"

Comment: I got `Searching for lxml
Best match: lxml 3.4.0
Processing lxml-3.4.0-py2.6-win-amd64.egg
lxml 3.4.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.4.0-py2.6-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for lxml
Finished processing dependencies for lxml` and again the same error.

Comment: Can you import a module of docx like from docx import Document?

Comment: Checked it now and possibly no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symptom can arise when you have both a legacy version and a new version of python-docx installed. I recommend you uninstall both completely and then install python-docx using `pip`. In general I recommend avoiding the use of `easy_install` anymore.

The legacy versions (v0.2.x) have the install-package name 'docx'. The new version uses the name 'python-docx' (although both import as 'docx' once installed). If you installed with `pip` doing the uninstall/reinstall would look something like this:

```
$ pip freeze
...
docx
...
python-docx
...

$ pip uninstall docx
...
$ pip uninstall python-docx
...
$ pip install python-docx
...
```

It sounds like you used `easy_install` originally, so you might need to uninstall manually, although I would try first and see if `pip` will get it done for you. If not, a quick search on `python easy_install uninstall` will lead you to useful resources. It might involve visiting "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\" and removing any files or directories that start with 'docx' or 'python-docx'.

This should get you further along. If it still gives you trouble after doing this, let me know the new symptoms. You should be able to install pretty transparently on an uncorrupted Python installation if you use `pip`.

Comment: Now I'm getting the erorr: `Downloading/unpacking python-docx
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-docx/: There was a p
roblem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: erro
r:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algori
thm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-docx/ when looking for dow
nload links for python-docx`

Comment: `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: There was a problem confi
rming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links
for python-docx
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-docx/: There was a p`

Comment: `roblem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: erro
r:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algori
thm>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-docx/ when looking for dow
nload links for python-docx
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-docx
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-docx
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Nir\pip\pip.log`

Comment: Sounds like you're having trouble with your network connection or something. You can see the files it's looking for here on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-docx/

Comment: My network connection is functioning. pip still gives me this error and suppose I use easy_install I get the same error while importing `import python-docx` (etree again couldn't be found)

Comment: The import statement should be `import docx`, or much more commonly, `from docx import Document`. As I mentioned above, the install package names differ, but the import module names are both 'docx'. I can't help you diagnose your network configuration, but it appears to be choking on the SSL certificate from PyPI. Can you access the URL I mentioned above in a browser?

Comment: Yes I can. and it writes me again `module not found` about this import.

Comment: Ok, well, that would indicate the problem isn't with python-docx or with PyPI. I think you'll need to look at your Python installation for the answers. You might try the install on another machine if you have one, to satisfy yourself that it's an issue local to your particular install. I don't believe I can help you any further with this.

Comment: Thanks. On my ubuntu I succeeded installing it so kind of problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting same 'DLL load failed' error. Stupid mistake on my part, but had installed 32 bit Python on to 64 bit Windows. Un-installed 32 bit version, installed 64 bit version - problem sorted.