# No Module found error when i installed docx

Tags: python

I have installed the "docx" package for python.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('inp.docx')

for p in document.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python-docx cannot be imported to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404228/python-docx-cannot-be-imported-to-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please do the below.

open cmd and type pip install python-docx

if  it fails, use pip3 install python-docx

Comment: Wow thanks for the help, this has helped me so much. been freeking